# Files and folders from Windows need admin permission to open or have the executable bit set now that they're on a Linux install

Tags: permissions

The files in my pictures folder from Windows, transferred to and then back from an external hard drive to be kept during a disk-wiping install of Ubuntu, were all set as executable. I fixed those, then I tried to open a subfolder to check that out but I needed admin permission to do so! How can I fix the permissions of my files and folders?

Comment: The folders require being executable. If there are only a few folders, you can set them manually, but if there are way too much to be handled manually, try running `find /path/to/mainFolder -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;`. If the files belong to your user, you won't need root permissions, but if they are not, you need to add sudo at the beginning of the command.

Comment: And what about the admin permissions thing? Ah, is it the chown command?

Comment: If you need everything to be owned by your user, you can run `sudo chown username:username /path/to/mainFolder -R` to change the owner of every single file and folder

Comment: Hmm, attempting to cd into the directory after doing sudo chown wolfboyft:wolfboyft directoryname still yields permission denied... EDIT: executable bit was not set and that's what I needed.

Comment: If `cd` gives permission error, there are still some folders that do not have the execution bit set. Check all the folders back to root `/`.(I mean, `/path`, `/path/to` and so...). If after that `ls` gives permission error, you need to change read bit of those files. If you need them to be only readable by you, use `chmod u+r "files"`.

Comment: I got it straightened out. All much appreciated.

Comment: @EmreTalha condider rolling all of your help into an answer that can be voted upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can point this bash script at a directory to fix it up, works for my use case. Some files become executable, others don't.  This removes executable from all of them. And then everything has others-writeable, which files made on ext4 in my home directory don't. I could not see any other differences in stuff taken from NTFS and put in ext4. The ownership was already in order.

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -type f -exec chmod -x {} \; # Remove executable from all files
find "$1" -exec chmod o-w {} \; # Remove others-writable from everything
```

Answer (score 2):

After copying a folder that doesn't originate from a Linux partition (ext4, bttrfs, zfs...) folder and file ownership and permissions might not be suitable for a non-root user.

The first thing to consider is changing the ownership of the files. This is accomplished with:

`sudo chown username:groupname /path/to/files -R`(username and groupname are usually the same for a single user setup)

After this, folders require having their execution bit set in order to be accessed.

`find /path/to/files -type d -exec chmod +x {} \;`

Lastly, the read and write permissions of the files might require some changes. If all the files are required to be both read and written:

`chmod +rw /path/to/files -R`

More info about [file permissions](https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-file-permissions/).